# Laravel go though 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I am trying to get it working in php laravel to get data from 2 tables.

§1. I need to get all "videos" (the table) that also is in the table "categories_in_videos" as "video_id" and print out the "category_id" also in that query.

Table videos:

```
 video_id   title       thumbnail   views   created_at updated_at   duration    isHD
```

table categories_in_videos (example):

```
  video_id  category_id   created_at            updated_at
  5022      16            0000-00-00 00:00:00   0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I have ready alot about it, but cannot figure it out. Hope someone can help me though this.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked laravel relationships http://three.laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#relationships

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work, can you help me? SELECT v.video_id, v.title from videos v WHERE EXISTS(select id from categories_in_videos where video_id = v.id and category_id=22)